# Very slow hot reloading after font-awesome has been added to Vue.js as a component

Tags: javascript, docker, vue.js, webpack, windows-10

I recently have started project for fun in Vue.js because this framework seems to be fun to work with. I have decided to add https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome component. Unfortunately after use it in one of my Vue components:

```
<template>
  <div class="success-box-wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-header">
        <span class="close">x</span>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">

      </div>
      <div class="box-footer">
        <div class="checkmark-circle">
          <div class="background"></div>
          <font-awesome-icon fa :icon="faCheck"/>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { faCheck } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export default {
  name: 'SuccessBox',
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
      faCheck,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Webpack seem to build project very slow.
`DONE  Compiled successfully in 54369ms10:04:26 AM`
Not just after adding `<font-awesome-icon fa :icon="faCheck"/>` but after any change. I tried to eject webpack outside Vue but nothing seem to work well. Maybe i shouldn't use font-awesoma as a component? maybe i should use in a "old" way by inserting CDN href ?

```
node_1  |  WAIT  Compiling...10:03:32 AM
node_1  |
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 0% compiling
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 10% building 0/0 modules 0 active
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 10% building 0/0 modules 0 active
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 40% building 0/0 modules 0 active
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 40% building 0/1 modules 1 active /usr/src/app/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/src/app/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!/usr/src/app/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js??ref--13-0!/usr/sr
c/app/src/components/SuccessBox.vue
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 70% building 1/1 modules 0 active
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 40% building 1/2 modules 1 active /usr/src/app/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"593dd390-vue-loader-template"}!/usr/src/app/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loade
rs/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!/usr/src/app/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/src/app/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!/usr/src/app/src/components/SuccessBox.vue?vue&type=template&id=6d8cce10&scoped=true&
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 40% building 1/3 modules 2 active /usr/src/app/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!/usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/usr/src/app/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/src/app/node_modul
es/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!/usr/src/app/src/components/SuccessBox.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 40% building 1/4 modules 3 active /usr/src/app/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!/usr/src/app/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--8-oneO
f-1-2!/usr/src/app/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!/usr/src/app/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/src/app/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!/usr/src/app/src/components/SuccessBox.vue?vue&type=style&in
dex=0&id=6d8cce10&lang=scss&scoped=true&
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 40% building 2/4 modules 2 active /usr/src/app/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!/usr/src/app/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--8-oneO
f-1-2!/usr/src/app/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!/usr/src/app/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/src/app/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!/usr/src/app/src/components/SuccessBox.vue?vue&type=style&in
dex=0&id=6d8cce10&lang=scss&scoped=true&
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 54% building 3/4 modules 1 active /usr/src/app/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!/usr/src/app/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!/usr/src/app/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ref--8-oneO
f-1-2!/usr/src/app/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!/usr/src/app/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!/usr/src/app/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!/usr/src/app/src/components/SuccessBox.vue?vue&type=style&in
dex=0&id=6d8cce10&lang=scss&scoped=true&
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 70% building 4/4 modules 0 active
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 70% building 4/4 modules 0 active
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 70% finish module graph
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 70% finish module graph FlagDependencyExportsPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 70% sealing
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 70% sealing WarnCaseSensitiveModulesPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 72% basic dependencies optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 72% dependencies optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 73% advanced dependencies optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 73% after dependencies optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 71% chunk graph
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 71% after chunk graph
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 71% after chunk graph WebAssemblyModulesPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 74% optimizing
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 74% basic module optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 75% module optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 75% advanced module optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 76% after module optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 76% basic chunk optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 76% basic chunk optimization EnsureChunkConditionsPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 76% basic chunk optimization RemoveEmptyChunksPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 76% basic chunk optimization MergeDuplicateChunksPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 77% chunk optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 77% advanced chunk optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 77% advanced chunk optimization SplitChunksPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 77% advanced chunk optimization RemoveEmptyChunksPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 77% after chunk optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 78% module and chunk tree optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 78% after module and chunk tree optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 79% basic chunk modules optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 80% chunk modules optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 80% advanced chunk modules optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 81% after chunk modules optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 81% module reviving
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 81% module reviving RecordIdsPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 82% module order optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 82% advanced module order optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 83% before module ids
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 83% before module ids NamedModulesPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 83% module ids
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 84% module id optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 84% module id optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 85% chunk reviving
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 85% chunk reviving RecordIdsPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 85% chunk order optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 85% chunk order optimization OccurrenceOrderChunkIdsPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 86% before chunk ids
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 86% before chunk ids NamedChunksPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 86% chunk id optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% after chunk id optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record modules
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record modules RecordIdsPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record chunks
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 87% record chunks RecordIdsPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 88% hashing
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 88% after hashing
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 88% after hashing HotModuleReplacementPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 89% record hash
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 89% module assets processing
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 90% chunk assets processing
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 90% additional chunk assets processing
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 90% additional chunk assets processing HotModuleReplacementPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 91% recording
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 91% recording HotModuleReplacementPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 92% additional asset processing
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 92% chunk asset optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% after chunk asset optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% asset optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 94% after asset optimization
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 94% after seal
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting HtmlWebpackPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 95% emitting CopyPlugin
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting CopyPlugin
node_1  |  DONE  Compiled successfully in 54369ms10:04:26 AM
node_1  |
node_1  | <s> [webpack.Progress] 100%
node_1  |
node_1  |
node_1  |   App running at:
node_1  |   - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
node_1  |
node_1  |   It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.
node_1  |   Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/
```

**EDIT WORKAROUND-LIKE SOLUTION:**

Previously i ran `yarn serve` inside docker container. It cause very long hot reload. When i run it directly inside Windows it compiles in 500**ms**. I leave it as unresolved question because i still don't know why it is so slow on Docker.

Comment: Apparently this is a known issue: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/other/tree-shaking.

If you follow the link you can find a few workarounds you can try

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately only "Use deep imports" workaround worked for me but not fully. It dropped build time from 54s. to 19s which is unfortunately still to much for me :/

Answer (score 0):

Having just had a nightmare couple of days with this issue, I think I may have found a fix for it.

Firstly, for me, it wasn't after adding any particular package via yarn/npm. Also, I'm having to use Windows as a host OS with Linux containers.

I started a new project with vue-cli, everything was working fine, after dockerizing it, the HMR was just unusably slow.

There seems to be 2 main aspects at play here, the port being used and also the `node_modules/` build time.

Fixing either one didn't help me very much but fixing both have HMR very close to running natively again.

So these were the things I added to fix:

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:

  front-end:
    container_name: my-front-end
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules' # <---- this enables a much faster start/reload
    ports:
      # default port does work but slow without mounting node_modules (above)
      # - '8080:8080'
      # for some reason HMR breaks completely when not using the same port as the container.
      # - '8007:8080'
      # - '8006:8007'
      # port 8007 set up in vue.config
      - '8007:8007'
    #   this is now also done in the vue.config
    # environment: 
      # - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

`vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        public: "localhost:8007",
        port: 8007,
        disableHostCheck: true,
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/,
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
            poll: 300,
        },
    },
};
```

I hope this helps somebody.